# Maven Library Without Version on Android

Tags: android, gradle, module, android-library

Is there anyway to create a maven Library for Android and publishing it without pushing new release with new release tag version so we are not required to specify the version when we use it in other project. but maybe gradle will check if there is new version available and if so it will be autoupdated to use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

- It is something on client app side to do, if they include your library module version in their build.gradle like , x.+ rather than specific numbered version, then they will get the latest released version for next their next build.

  For example, i.e 2.+ rather than some specific version like , 2.6